# Skip saveas prompt and automaticly download file

Tags: html, download

I work on Angular 1 web application and I am using **HTML download Attribute**
`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`
in order to provide user functionality of downloading presented data in Excel spreadsheet. What I would like to have is by clicking on download link have data **automatically opened**, not to have **"save as" prompt**.
Is this possible, or is this user-browser setting which due to security reasons can't be overridden/forced?

Comment: remove the download attribute and add a target attribute

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser setting that is not under the control of the page author.

(Here, download and automatically open this `.exe` file that has been packed with malware).